# No component for supporting the service Abp.Zero.Configuration.IAbpZeroConfig was found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I implemented a custom ExternalLogin exactly like [aspnetboilerplate document](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management?searchKey=externalLogin):

```
public class MyExternalAuthSource : DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>, ITransientDependency
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "MyCustomSource"; }
    }

    public override Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, Tenant tenant)
    {

    }
}
```

and I registered it as:

```
public class ImmenseWebModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.Modules.Zero().UserManagement.ExternalAuthenticationSources.Add<MyExternalAuthSource>();
    }
}
```

but after running project I crossed with below exception:

> No component for supporting the service Abp.Zero.Configuration.IAbpZeroConfig was found

When I added `Abp.Zero.Common.dll` I will get below error:

> The type 'DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource' exists in both 'Abp.Zero.Common, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Abp.Zero, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

If I removed `Abp.Zero.dll` I will get another exceptions.

**Project type is ASP.Net MVC 5**

any help would be truly appreciated.

**UPDATE1:**

After defining a binding as below :

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I got the exception:

> Can't create component 'Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobStore' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobStore' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[[Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobInfo, Abp, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' which was not registered.

So after some search I came to this conclusion that I have to implement `IRepository` and register it as(just to be run):

```
public interface ISampleBlogRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{

}
```

and register it:

```
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(
                typeof(IRepository<>))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof(ISampleBlogRepository<>)).LifestyleTransient().Named("IRepositoryImplementation"));
            IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(
                typeof(IRepository<,>))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof(ISampleBlogRepository<,>)).LifestyleTransient().Named("IRepositoryOfPrimaryKeyImplementation"));
```

But unfortunately I faced new problem as :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and part of Stack:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkDefaultOptionsExtensions.GetUnitOfWorkAttributeOrNull(IUnitOfWorkDefaultOptions unitOfWorkDefaultOptions, MethodInfo methodInfo) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkDefaultOptionsExtensions.cs:11
>      Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkInterceptor.cs:32
>      Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +443
>      Castle.Proxies.IRepository`2Proxy_1.GetAllListAsync(Expression`1 predicate) +155
>      Abp.Configuration.d__3.MoveNext() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.Zero.Common\Configuration\SettingStore.cs:40
>      System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31

**Why it is complicated, I faced to new exception in each step.**

**UPDATE2:**

If I disable `bg` jobs by `Configuration.BackgroundJobs.IsJobExecutionEnabled = false;` I got another exception as below:

> Can't create component 'Abp.MultiTenancy.TenantCache 2[[x.Web.x.Core.Tenant, x.Web.x.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[MARCO.Web.ImmenseLib.Core.User, x.Web.x.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> Abp.MultiTenancy.TenantCache 2[[x.Web.x.Core.Tenant, x.Web.x.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[x.Web.x.Core.User, x.Web.x.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository 1[[x.Web.x.Core.Tenant, x.Web.x.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroCommonModule))]` to your module:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroCommonModule))]
public class ImmenseWebModule : AbpModule
{
    // ...
}
```

> Method 'ExecuteActionFilterAsync' in type 'Abp.WebApi.Validation.AbpApiValidationFilter' from assembly 'Abp.Web.Api, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Add these bindings: [AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa/Web.config#L46-L261](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/debbb14953732513110754407f226fe5a837c513/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa/Web.config#L46-L261)

It is mentioned in issue [#2494](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2494) that this binding helps:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166365/discussion-between-aaron-and-aria).