# Trying to obtain the Windows Identity of the Logged on User in AccountController

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

using framework asp.net core - on .net core MVC jquery

In the account controller, I am attempting to obtain the user currently logged in to that machine on an intranet network. ie the windows authenticated user.

If I try `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` is just returns the identity of the application pool. not what I need.

I have anonymous turned off and windows auth turned on in both the `launchsettings.json` and the IIS settings.

I understand that the identity middleware for abp framework I'm using is table based so the Controllers `'User'` property is not what I need either.

I am wondering whether this is a limitation of the .net core?

Comment: `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Yes that would return the Table based user.  However I am trying to grab the identity of the logged 'windows' user -  but I don't think it is going to be possible.  I looked at the standard microsoft template project for asp.net core using windows authentication - the Model for the User property comes from RazorPageBase.User which is a ClaimsPrincipal type.

Comment: `HttpContext.User.Identity` *is* of `ClaimsPrincipal` type.

Comment: ok, yes correct - i just took a peek at the source code for RazorPageBase and the User property is : "public virtual ClaimsPrincipal User => ViewContext?.HttpContext?.User;"

Comment: i think becuase the abp middleware set the identity source (table) so if the user has not logged in, then that property will be empty.  I am trying to dig out the windows logged on user before they log in - that is why i'm stuck as it just returns my app pool identity

Answer (score 0):

You need to **disable Anonymous Authentication** and enable **Windows Authentication** for a specific page like **Login** page. This way, you say the Login page requires NTLM. So browser sends authenticated user information.  And you can retrieve it with `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

Then there's next challenge! Authenticating this user with ABP. For this one, you can check out [this StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46169719/1767482)

Comment: I tried adding [AbpAuthorize()] to the controller but i get an error that creates a recursive loop . https://localhost:44323/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252F

Comment: if i could only have the site start on a different page i might make some progress...

Comment: change the default landing page to your windows authenticated page.

Comment: Put `[AbpAllowAnonymous]` on `Login` method.